# Can the uninstaller be configured after the setup is complete?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a list of files to be deleted in the [UninstallDelete] section and some code to run when the uninstall step occurs.

My application is initially installed with InnoSetup but updates are provided without using it; the application just downloads the updated files and restarts. Now the list of files to be removed when uninstalling as well as the custom code might change with the update, but since the setup didn't run again the uninstaller is no longer up to date.

Is there any way to work around that without running the Inno installer on every update? Could I e.g. just download updated versions of the unins000.exe/dat and replay the old ones, or is there another way?

Comment: Wouldn't be an option that you would distribute updates again as setup packages, just your app. updater would run them (very) silently ? I don't know if uninstall binaries with their logs are portable. For sure they are not portable if any of the installed files is installed conditionally (since you could record something which will not be found on the user's machine). In any case, distributing uninstaller for something that was installed on a different machine doesn't look like a reliable way and I would personally avoid it (even if it coincidentally work).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's probably the best way to go. The application usually runs elevated so this would create two UAC popups rather than one, but I don't see any other downside atm.

Comment: It depends on the process which executes the setup. A rule of thumb is distributing your setup with the `PrivilegesRequired` directive set to the same privileges level as your updater. Out of curiosity, almost every well known product update is distributed that way (even e.g. Windows Updates). That is also because e.g. network administrators can verify and execute a single update setup file rather than copying a set of files to their network clients.